# What is the difference between the normal Xbox One controller and the 'Play and Charge Kit' version?

Tags: pc, controllers

I'm planning on buying a Xbox One controller in order to use it to play games on my PC. I'd like to ask what is the difference between the normal one(which includes an USB) and the one with Play and Charge Kit.

Also, how long do the batteries last? Do I have to recharge them every time they run out?

Sorry if these are simple questions I've never used a console.

Comment: If you have the play and charge kit, then there's currently no reason to worry about battery life. You are _required_ to keep the controller connected. Microsoft hasn't released a wireless adapter yet (it's coming some time after the release of Windows 10 and only on Windows 10).

Comment: What if I am buying the normal one? Do I need something to recharge the AA batteries? Also, how much do the batteries last?

Comment: Same situation. The controller doesn't necessarily _need_ batteries, just if you're using it wirelessly.  However, the controller works fine when connected, even without batteries.

Comment: So, if I buy the normal one, without any play and charge kit, I will be able to use the controller non-stop?

Comment: If you stay connected, then yes I'd imagine.

Comment: Are you sure about this? Couldn't find anything on the Internet.

Comment: I have a controller connected to my computer right now with the play and charge kit.  I removed the battery pack from it and left it connected and it's still working. _Yes_ I'm sure...

Comment: Yeah, alright, I'm pretty sure it will work, I just want to make sure it won't run out of battery after a period of time. Thanks a lot for the help, will wait for other answers too.

Comment: Hey, coming back. Was wondering if it's worth getting a wireless Xbox One controller and hook it up to pc with a micro usb cable(which i already have)? This one is cheaper. Also, it's the same thing as getting the normal controller that has an usb included, right? (non-stop playing, since it's connected to PC).

Comment: I have this one http://www.ebay.com/itm/SAMSUNG-OEM-HOME-WALL-TRAVEL-CHARGER-AC-POWER-ADAPTER-USB-CABLE-SYNC-WIRE-CORD-/400563260502

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no difference in between the normal and the play and charge kit controller. Both are the same. The only difference is, that you get a battery pack and a USB-cable with your controller.

If you want to play on the PC, you can buy any other USB-cable and forget about the battery pack. In order to use the controller on the PC you'll need to permanently connect the controller to your PC using the USB-cable.

If you want to play on the Xbox too with the same controller, the battery pack is worth it. The battery holds about 10-15 hours if I play normally. This means, I never emptied it on a single session. The special about the USB-cable from the play and charge kit is the LED at the controller end. It will display the charge status of your controller.

Comment: So, basically, I could play non-stop if I stay connected throught the wire to the PC?

Comment: Yes right. The controller just gets the power from the usb-cable. The battery is useless for this use-case. It only matters if you gonna play wireless on your xBox with the same controller too.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help. Also, will I ever have to change the AA batteries inside the controller?

Comment: Well do you mean really batteries? If you charge it with the usb-cable I would suggest to remove the batteries at all. Otherwise it could get seriously damaged. You cannot load batteries!

Comment: Oh, I was reffering to the batteries you put in the back of the controller.

Comment: Yes I mean the same. :-D Except you mean accumulator?

Comment: No, that's fine, thanks for the help, will buy one.

Comment: By the way, if this answers your question, you can mark it to help others to find the right answer faster.

Comment: Hey, coming back. Was wondering if it's worth getting a wireless Xbox One controller and hook it up to pc with a micro usb cable(which i already have)? This one is cheaper. Also, it's the same thing as getting the normal controller that has an usb included, right? (non-stop playing, since it's connected to PC).

Comment: I have this one: http://www.ebay.com/itm/SAMSUNG-OEM-HOME-WALL-TRAVEL-CHARGER-AC-POWER-ADAPTER-USB-CABLE-SYNC-WIRE-CORD-/400563260502

Comment: Well if the usb standard is the same as on the controller. I'm not sure, but should be easy to find via google. I'm not sure if its an micro or mini usb is used for the controller